# IdentityServer4 - The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read email is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to use Microsoft Account as an external login in IdentityServer4 , I created a new app under Microsoft Application portal and configured it as the following :

1. I added new web Platform
2. under Delegated Permissions I added the following permissions

   - User.Read
   - email
   - openId
   - Profile

and here is the code that I am using in IdentityServer4 to access Microsoft Account by adding email as a scope :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount("MicrosoftAccount", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = "ClientId";
        options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        options.Scope.Add("email");

});
```

but when trying to access Microsoft Account I am getting the following error

***The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read email is not valid***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with OpenID Connect, you must always include `openid` in the requested scopes list. For completeness, here's a working setup:

```
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("email");
```

This is documented by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#openid-connect-scopes):

> If an app performs sign-in by using OpenID Connect, it must request the openid scope.

It's actually just part of the OpenID [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html):

> OpenID Connect requests MUST contain the openid scope value. If the openid scope value is not present, the behavior is entirely unspecified. Other scope values MAY be present. Scope values used that are not understood by an implementation SHOULD be ignored.

The Microsoft Account implementation in ASP.NET Core [only sets the `user.read` scope](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/MicrosoftAccountOptions.cs#L26) by default, which is why you need to add it yourself. It seems that the Google implementation in ASP.NET Core *does* [include the `openid` scope](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleOptions.cs#L25) by default, which explains why you might be seeing different results with different providers.

Given that you've added the `profile` scope to the Delegated Permissions list, you might also want to include this in your requested scopes list.

This explains the reason for your error, but a simpler approach might be to just leave the requested scope list alone entirely (just using the default of `user.read`). Doing this in my example, I still get the same claims list in my example, which is comprised of `nameidentifier`, `name`, `givenname`, `surname` and `emailaddress`. This could explain why the OpenID specific scopes are not requested by default.